# How do I Write an int16 to a binary file?

Tags: c#, file, binary

I have a several config forms from where I write to a config file.
How can write an int16 to a file, because the maximum value is 100 and I would like save a place in the file?

```
private void butSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (valChanged == true)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Assembly assem = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(assem.Location);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(dir, "./conf/config.dat");
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                BinaryWriter wr = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                fs.Position = 0;
                wr.Write(checkBox1.Checked);
                wr.Write(checkBox2.Checked);
                fs.Position = 16;
                wr.Write(numericUpDown1.Value);
                wr.Write(numericUpDown2.Value);
                wr.Write(numericUpDown3.Value);
                wr.Write(numericUpDown4.Value);
                wr.Close();
                Form1 main = new Form1();
                main.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Would you like to create a new config file", "File not found!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is 100 the maximum value? Would `byte` (or `sbyte`) not save you more space? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: For this task probably byte would be even better for you if your goal is really to save place in the file. It can hold 127 positive values - so more than you need- even if signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to `short` to use [`BinaryWriter.Write(short)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/091b1s67.aspx)

```
 wr.Write((short)numericUpDown1.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var file =  File.Create("out.bin"))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
{
    foreach (short value in list)
    {
        writer.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brian plz post some explanation when you answer to OP, its a good habbit to learn and to clear your way of seeing the question.

Comment: @Jai - I appreciate the feedback Jai, and will do so in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: It will be great to see you again. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

short is an Int16, but if 100 is your max you only need 8 bits and byte will work.  This will take half of the amount of space as using a short.

```
wr.Write((byte)numericUpDown1.Value);
```